# get compiler error in swift indexOf()

Tags: swift

So I had a function like this:

```
    var localIndices: [ChartHighlight] = []

    for globalHighlight in globalIndices
    {
        if let globalSet = data?.dataSets[globalHighlight.dataSetIndex]
        {
            if globalSet.dynamicType === dataSetType
            {
                let chartData = getChartData(dataSetType)

                if (chartData == nil)
                {
                    return globalIndices
                }

                let localdataSetIndex = chartData!.dataSets.indexOf(globalSet)
                if (localdataSetIndex != nil)
                {
                    localIndices.append(ChartHighlight(xIndex: globalHighlight.xIndex, dataSetIndex: localdataSetIndex!, stackIndex: globalHighlight.stackIndex))
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return globalIndices
            }
        }
    }
```

The compiler complains at

`let localdataSetIndex = chartData!.dataSets.indexOf(globalSet)`

saying that

> Cannot convert value of type 'IChartDataSet' to expected argument type '@noescape (IChartDataSet) throws -> Bool'

I am confused why I cannot use normal `indexOf()` for `[IChartDataSet]`. Is this related that `chartData!.dataSets` is `[IChartDataset]` while `IChartDataset` is a `protocol` type? 
I don't see swift doc mentioning this or I missed it...

Comment: Is your `IChartDataSet` conforms to `Equatable`? Probably not, that's why you can't use usual `indexOf`.

Comment: @AlexanderDoloz I checked it does not conform. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use `indexOf` method with element as input param, your element type of `dataSets` which is `IChartDataSet` must conform to `Equatable` protocol as you can see from `CollectionType` extension definition:

```
    extension CollectionType where Generator.Element : Equatable {
       /// Returns the first index where `value` appears in `self` or `nil` if
        /// `value` is not found.
        ///
        /// - Complexity: O(`self.count`).
        @warn_unused_result
        public func indexOf(element: Self.Generator.Element) -> Self.Index?
    }
```

Or you can use predicate closure instead:

```
let localdataSetIndex = chartData!.dataSets.indexOf { $0 === globalSet }
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Actually, I'm developing based on an open source project https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/. Yes IChartDatSet does not conform Equatable. Could you give an example how Equatable should be implemented in this case?

Comment: my swift doc saying (I am using Dash3) the definition is `@warn_unused_result func indexOf(_ element: Self.Generator.Element) -> Self.Index?`. Hmm, shame that the doc is not correct. Is this swift 2.2 latest change?